# Contents block overlaps document body in help page

Tags: bug, comments, design, help-center

Opening [comment formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) from the comment section leads to a page body overlapped with the contents block.

Steps to reproduce (if using direct link is not good enough):

1. Click "Add a comment" below any post.
2. Click "help" link on the right.
3. Click "Learn more about formatting".

> [image: learn more]

These actions will lead to the next page:

> [image: overlapped block]

Scrolling page down fixes the issue.

[Screencast of win10](https://www.screencast.com/t/DmM4kbIv)

Looks like only Stack Overflow site family is affected.

Tested under:

- Windows 7: Chrome 62.0.3202.94, Firefox 57.0
- Windows 10: Chrome 62.0.3202.94, Yandex 17.10.0.2017
- Android 7.0: Chrome 62.0.3202.84
- iOS 11: Chrome 62.0.3202.70

Comment: No repro in Chrome/Win10. please add your browser and OS

Comment: @rene added! Did you try direct link too?

Comment: I'm on the same chrome and I tried everything you tried. Are you on  an insane monitor width? Zoomed-in?

Comment: @rene I'm asking you again: did you try [direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)? MSE is not affected. Only SOs!

Comment: It's initialized with `position: fixed`, which removed on first scroll or resize event

Comment: see https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ggu8.gif

Comment: see https://www.screencast.com/t/DmM4kbIv

Comment: @rene where you got +2846 rep? :) Do you use any browser extensions? What happens if you make a refresh already opened page?

Comment: @rene, did you try without tampermonkey and other?

Comment: @vp_arth with extensions disabled I still can't repro. I can repro in incognito mode though.

Comment: I get the same issue. When I scroll down and scroll back up the issue is fine and it sits in the right place. My browser Win10/Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0